# Past simple or past continuous?

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

> 1 Being students, they *didn't have* much money and they usually *worked* as waiters at weekends.

Why do we need to use the  past simple?

> 2 While they *were studying*, they *were working* as waiters at weekends.

Is it right to use the past continuous in this case?

> 3 I *worked* from 09-00 to 18-00.

This  means that I worked only from 09-00 to 18-00, right?

> 4 I *was working* from 09-00 to 18-00.

This means that I was in the process of working from 09-00 to 18-00, but I started work before 09-00 and is not a fact that I finished my work at 18-00. I am right?

Answer (score 0):

*I worked from 9:00 to 6:00* (That's the typical way of indicating time in America.) means that in the past you were definitely working from 9 to 6, but technically tells nothing about whether you were working at 5 or 7. However, it would be odd to only state part of your work time.  *I was working* means the same thing, but it is continuous, so you can add on an event like i was working from 9 to 6 while it rained.